# calculate frequencies for non existing values

Tags: python, pandas

Im using `pyreadstat` to open a SPSS (.sav) file, and think of a data frame where the columns are questions from a survey. I'd like to calculate frequencies for each column grouped by some other columns by first melting the data and then calculate the frequencies.

```
import pandas as pd
import pyreadstat


df, meta = pyreadstat.read_sav('df_test.sav')
questions = ['q1', 'q2', 'q3']

df_m = df.melt(value_vars=questions, var_name='question', id_vars=['yearmonth','grp']).dropna()
df_m.groupby(['yearmonth', 'grp', 'question', 'value']).agg({'value': 'count'})
```

This will give us an nice output like this:

```
                               value
yearmonth grp  question value       
2020-08   Grp1 q1       1.0        1
               q2       1.0        1
               q3       1.0        1
2020-09   Grp1 q1       1.0       50
                        2.0        4
                        4.0        3
               q2       1.0       42
                        2.0       12
               q3       1.0       52
                        2.0        2
          Grp2 q1       1.0       98
                        3.0        2
                        4.0        1
               q2       1.0       89
                        2.0        6
               q3       1.0       86
                        2.0        9
```

But here's the tricky part. I know for a fact that q1 has 5 different answers (1,2,3,4,5) but obviously no one has answered anything but 1, 3 or 4, q2 has 5 different answers as well, but q3 has 3 different answers. I'd like the give the output 0 for the non existing values so it looks like this:

```
                               value
yearmonth grp  question value       
2020-08   Grp1 q1       1.0        1
               q1       2.0        0
               q1       3.0        0
               q1       4.0        0
               q1       5.0        0
....................................
....................................
....................................
               q3       1.0       86
                        2.0        9
                        3.0        0
```

pyreadstat has a nice feature where you can read the `meta` from the .sav file and the variables values and their value labels:

```
{'q1': {1.0: '1', 2.0: '2', 3.0: '3', 4.0: '4', 5.0: '5'},
 'q2': {1.0: '1', 2.0: '2', 3.0: '3', 4.0: '4', 5.0: '5'},
 'q3': {1.0: '1', 2.0: '2', 3.0: '3'}}
```

df_m.groupby dict:

```
{'value': {('2020-08', 'Grp1', 'q1', 1.0): 1,
  ('2020-08', 'Grp1', 'q2', 1.0): 1,
  ('2020-08', 'Grp1', 'q3', 1.0): 1,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp1', 'q1', 1.0): 50,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp1', 'q1', 2.0): 4,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp1', 'q1', 4.0): 3,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp1', 'q2', 1.0): 42,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp1', 'q2', 2.0): 12,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp1', 'q3', 1.0): 52,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp1', 'q3', 2.0): 2,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp2', 'q1', 1.0): 98,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp2', 'q1', 3.0): 2,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp2', 'q1', 4.0): 1,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp2', 'q2', 1.0): 89,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp2', 'q2', 2.0): 6,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp2', 'q3', 1.0): 86,
  ('2020-09', 'Grp2', 'q3', 2.0): 9}}
```

Can I somehow use this dict to count frequencies for non existing values in the data frame? Or insert the non existing values into the grouped frame?

Comment: It's hard to replicated your data. Can you do do `df_m.groupby(['yearmonth', 'grp', 'question', 'value']).agg({'value': 'count'}).to_dict()` and post the output?

Comment: Yes, ofc. I've added it now @QuangHoang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try `reindex`:

```
(a['value'].unstack(level=(2,3), fill_value=0)
     .reindex([(k,x) for k,v in meta.items() for x in v], axis=1, fill_value=0)
     .stack(level=(0,1))
     .to_frame(name='value')
)
```

where `a` is `df_m.groupby(...).agg(...)`. Output:

```
                     value
2020-08 Grp1 q1 1.0    1.0
                2.0    0.0
                3.0    0.0
                4.0    0.0
                5.0    0.0
             q2 1.0    1.0
                2.0    0.0
                3.0    0.0
                4.0    0.0
                5.0    0.0
             q3 1.0    1.0
                2.0    0.0
                3.0    0.0
2020-09 Grp1 q1 1.0   50.0
                2.0    4.0
                3.0    0.0
                4.0    3.0
                5.0    0.0
             q2 1.0   42.0
                2.0   12.0
                3.0    0.0
                4.0    0.0
                5.0    0.0
             q3 1.0   52.0
                2.0    2.0
                3.0    0.0
        Grp2 q1 1.0   98.0
                2.0    0.0
                3.0    2.0
                4.0    1.0
                5.0    0.0
             q2 1.0   89.0
                2.0    6.0
                3.0    0.0
                4.0    0.0
                5.0    0.0
             q3 1.0   86.0
                2.0    9.0
                3.0    0.0
```

Comment: Oh, this is almost correct. But the reindex here assumes every column to have 1 to 5. But, the dict of meta values for the questions has a q3 with 1 to 3. I might be wrong doing the melting and grouping first. Maybe I should be using the dict of meta values in an earlier state?

Comment: @destinychoice sure, you can just construct the right index. see updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the dictionary, you can do as easy as when you are searching for a key, it is not encountered, to give it a default value or cast the dictionary to a *defaultdict* from **collections** library.

**For example**

```
dict_grouped_by = df_m.groupby(['yearmonth', 'grp', 'question', 'value']).agg({'value': 'count'}).to_dict()
val_count = dict_grouped_by['value']
```

**default value**

```
val_count.get(('2020-09', 'Grp2', 'q3', 3.0), 0) # returns 0
```

**use defaultdict**

```
from collections import defaultdict
def_dict = defaultdict(int, val_count)
def_dict[('2020-09', 'Grp2', 'q3', 3.0)] # returns 0
```

Comment: That would be an awful lot of searching. Suppose you have a couple of years and months, and hundred of groups.

Comment: No, the idea of this approach is that you do not need to create all the elements of the dictionary before searching. In the case of you not needing a specific key in your dict, it will **never be created** which is better in memory and CPU performance.